# Calling a method with a looping inside using a timer doesn't stop the method in the looping

Tags: c#

i have a problem when i call the method getQuerytoRun() using the Timer the looping inside doesn't seem to stop and doesn't finish itself i've tested it with a breakpoint and it seems it's continiuing it's looping adding value to 
the list

```
   //sets the list
class Queries
{
    public static List<string> query = new List<string>();
}
     //will read from db what queries will be getting
class Getvalue: Queries
{
    public static void getquerytorun(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string Conn = "Data Source= LPTP2018AM00031\\SQLSERVER2016;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Initial Catalog=Integral360;User ID=sa;Password=password";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Conn))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM BatchtoRun where Active = 1", conn);
                using (SqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    while (Reader.Read())
                    {
                        query.Add(Reader[2].ToString());
                    }
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
    }
}
//timer that checks the query every interval
class runvalue: Getvalue
{
    public static void Intervals()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(getquerytorun);
        Timer.Interval = 30000;
        Timer.Enabled = true;
        ////GetBatchToRun();
    }
    public static void RuntheQuery()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (object o in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }

}

          //run the consoleapp
class startrun: runvalue
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Intervals();
        RuntheQuery();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

i can't seem to figure out why it doesn't terminate when i call it using a timer

Comment: How many records does that query return?

Comment: How many rows are in your DB?  [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) will return true if there are more rows thereby continuing to loop.

Comment: only 3 but when i check in it breakpoint it continously runs infinitely

Comment: I think you need to dispose of the timer or stop it if you don't want it to continue.

Comment: I think there is not really enough debugging here, i mean this shouldnt be happening, so with extraordinary claims you need extraordinary proof. may i suggest disconnecting this query form the timer and ruining it just once. using a counter, break pointing on connection close, or something... You need to make the effort to really prove this beyond reasonable doubt with a clinical laboratory test

Comment: `[Timer]` [class][1]  will fires an event at regular intervals. If you want to run your query with a delay of 30000 millisecond you can use  `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep`


 


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2